# strange routing on one of local network servers

Tags: linux, networking, ping, routes, tcpdump

I have 2 local networks (2 offices connected with openvpn)

Network 1:

```
network 192.168.1.0/24
gateway 192.168.1.101
```

Network 2:

```
network 192.168.2.0/24
gateway 192.168.2.10
```

in network 192.168.1.0/24 I have 2 servers - 192.168.1.180 and 192.168.1.183
first run on Debian 6 and second one on Archlinux (yes, I know it is bad choice for servers). I have no firewall on the servers.

everything works fine, clients from 192.168.2.0 can connect to computers in 192.168.1.0 and back. Except one of servers - 192.168.1.180 (Archlinux). I can't connect to it and can't connect from it to any computer in 192.168.2.0. No ping, no traceroute.

```
output from 192.168.1.180:
route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.101   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

i run tcpdump on the gateway (192.168.1.101) and ping on 192.168.1.180 and get this:

```
tcpdump src 192.168.1.180

listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
14:23:57.354061 arp who-has 172.19.155.1 tell 192.168.1.180
14:23:58.357354 arp who-has 172.19.155.1 tell 192.168.1.180
...
```

why it looks for 172.19.155.1? I don't know what this strange IP means. I have no networks like this, no GW, nothing.
if I run ping on all other computer (for example ping from 192.168.1.183) I get:

```
tcpdump icmp

listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
14:29:36.834731 IP 192.168.1.183 > 192.168.2.10: ICMP echo request, id 3216, seq 1, length 64
14:29:36.956211 IP 192.168.2.10 > 192.168.1.183: ICMP echo reply, id 3216, seq 1, length 64
```

No one looks for this strange IP except 192.168.1.180. I cleaned arp table on 192.168.1.180 but nothing helps.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Comment: You say _"Except one of servers - 192.168.1.180 (Archlinux). I can connect to it and can connect from it to any computer in 192.168.2.0. No ping, no traceroute."_  -- Do you mean _cannot connect_?

Comment: Yes, sure, I can't connect it was a typing error

Comment: Does 192.168.1.180 have multiple interfaces?

Comment: No, only one - eth0. 192.168.1.180 and 192.168.1.183 have same configuration (but one is Debian and second is Arch)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have a default gw configuration exists on your server x.180/24 which points to 172.19.155.1. So, the server assumes all the traffic has to go via 172.19.155.1 and trying to resolve the gw. Look for a default gw configuration in your system, something like this

`0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.19.155.1`

use `ip route xxx`

You are able to see the packets in x.101/24 because it is an ARP request, which is broadcast MAC and you will see it on all directly connected devices.

Comment: Right, it looks like I have 172.19.155.1 as default GW but it is not true:  
  
`ip route default via 192.168.1.101 dev eth0 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.180`

Comment: can you try the reverse direction ping and capture the pkts. whats the behavior. C'mon it should get the 172.x ip from somewhere. Or try to configure a static ARP entry on both sides and then try a ping. See how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would do/check:

- Make absolutely sure that I don't have a second interface going somewhere (`ifconfig -a` should do it)
- I know, it's unlikely... but any chance a routing protocol is enabled on that server? You would see the routes in your routing table, though... which I understand is not the case.
- Run a grep on /etc and wherever you have config files for 172.19.55.1

Just my 2c.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. Not really solved, but at least it works now. The server must work 24/7 but it was my last chance and I rebooted it )) All work was stopped for 30 min but it was worthy of it.

I really don't understand wat happened with it. Some mystic problem.